# Databinding is not working with kendo grid in angular JS directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-grid

I am new to angular js and kendo UI. Here is my plunk [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYsbP2zgKVhCXctKH2z2?p=preview)

I have a directive and want to bind data to the kendo grid.

Script.js - code for module, controller and directive.

```
(function(){

  angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives']);


  angular.module('app').controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
    var data =  {
      accountlist: [
                        {accountnumber: '123456', accountname: 'Firm 1'},
                        {accountnumber: '111111', accountname: 'Firm 2'},
                        {accountnumber: '1234567', accountname: 'Firm 3'},
                        {accountnumber: '1234568', accountname: 'Firm 4'},
                        {accountnumber: '1234569', accountname: 'Firm 5'}
                    ]};
    $scope.ds = data;

  });

  angular.module('app').directive('mydir', function(){
      return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope:{
              ds:'='
            },
            controller:function($scope){},
            templateUrl: 'dir.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {

              $('#accountlistgrid').kendoGrid({
                dataSource:{
                  data: scope.ds.accountlist
                },
                selectable: true,
                columns: [
                        {
                            field: "accountnumber",
                            title: "Account"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "accountname",
                            title: "Firm Name"

                        }
                    ]
              });
            }

  }});


}());
```

HTML code:

```
  <head>
    <link data-require="kendoUI@*" data-semver="2014.2.716" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link data-require="kendoUI@*" data-semver="2014.2.716" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.3.6" data-semver="1.3.6" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="kendoUI@*" data-semver="2014.2.716" src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div>
      <mydir ds='ds'></mydir>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Why I am not able to see kendo grid?

Comment: You are missing `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in your Plunker.

Comment: Oh.. I missed basic thing. I have updated this in plunk. Still not able to see data. Some console error 'm is not function'

Comment: Will have a look. Are you required to use a specific version of Angular or Kendo?

Comment: Yes. angular 1.3.6 and any latest version of kendo.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: Yes. This worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a conflict between versions.

You can read about which versions work together [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites#supported-angularjs-versions).

For example, it states that the latest major release Kendo UI 2015.3.930 (Q3 2015) supports **AngularJS 1.4.0+**. Not sure if it's backwards compatible, but you can always try.

If you need Angular 1.3.6 you should otherwise use Kendo UI 2015.2.624 (Q2 2015):

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/PfVJjA55kL6l9fEMl8uX?p=preview