# angular with kendo grid in templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

(sorry if this is duplicate, but what i've found does **not** answer my question: 
[Databinding is not working with kendo grid in angular JS directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691098/databinding-is-not-working-with-kendo-grid-in-angular-js-directives)
)

I am trying to create a ***directive with a templateUrl containing a kendo grid, and use this directive in a controller***.

I can manage to bind some of the directive's attributes (e.g. my-grid-options, which is initialized in the controller) but *not* ***my-grid-id***.

What am I missing? (full plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kGPlfzoQfm2wFkOcSMSN?p=preview))

**the directive:**

```
Directives.myGrid = function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            myGridId: "=",
            myGridOptions: "="
        },
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'myGrid.html',
        link: function(scope) {
            //... some code using the myGridId
            scope.myGridId.....
        }
    }
}
```

**myGrid.html:**

```
<div kendo-grid="myGridId" k-options="myGridOptions" id="myGridId">      
</div>
```

**how I want to use it:**

```
<body ng-app='app' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
     <my-grid my-grid-id="mainGrid" my-grid-options="mainGridOptions"></my-grid>    
</body>
```

**controller:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.ds = [
          {Category:"Toys", Name: "Doll", Code: "p1", Special: false},  
          ....            
          {Category:"Stationary", Name: "Crayons", Code: "p4", Special: false}
        ];

    $scope.mainGridOptions = {            
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Category",
                title: "Category"
            },
            {
                field: "Name",
                title: "Name"
            },
            {
                field: "Code",
                title: "Code"
            }, 
            {
                field: "Special",
                title: "Special Offer"
            }, 
        ],
        dataSource: $scope.ds,
        sortable: true,
        selectable: true,
        resizable: true,
        pageable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        columnReorder: function (e) {
          //do something trivial... for example sake, but a more complex event is used
          $.each($scope.mainGrid.wrapper.find('tbody tr'), function () {
              var model = $scope.mainGrid.dataItem(this);
              if (model.Special === true) {
                  $(this).addClass('special-row');
              }
          });
        }
    };
  });
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It might be me being stupidly in a rush, but i don't see $scope.mainGrid variable anywhere in your controller. However, you do try to bind it to your directive using the attribute  'my-grid-id'...

Comment: @ocket-san i am trying to produce it through the kendo-grid in the directive. see how it works if I use directly a kendo-grid instead of a directive with a kendo-grid

Comment: Ok. Also, i tried to look at your plunkr link, but it timed out everytime. Could u fix that so i can have a better look? tnx

Comment: @ocket-san it worked for me but i also froze it now and checked from someone else and works as well. can you give it another go? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i got to see your plunk. I did a few changes and here is [the result](http://plnkr.co/edit/CE6ySg?p=preview).

You still got some problems in there. Check my changes in your directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myGrid', function(){
      return {
        scope: {
            gridId: "=",
            gridOptions: "="
        },
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'myGrid.html',
        link: function(scope) {
           console.log(gridId);
           console.log(scope.gridId);
            // var doMore = function() {
            //     $.each(scope.gridId.wrapper.find('tbody tr'), function () {
            //         var model = $scope.gridId.dataItem(this);
            //         if (model.Category === "Stationary") {
            //             $(this).addClass('stationary-row');
            //         }
            //     });
            // };

            // var extendReorder = function(baseReorder) {
            //     doMore();
            //     if (baseReorder)
            //         baseReorder();
            // };

            scope.gridOptions.columnReorder = extendReorder(scope.gridOptions.columnReorder);
        }
    };
  });
```

I removed the tranclude:"true", as it caused a directive collision. Then there were errors about you gridId being "undefined". I don't know what its purpose is, so i just gave it a value in the controller (check the plunk). If it is not completely what you want yet, let me know, i look further into it.

Comment: apparently you need to freeze.. since i'm also getting a timeout now :)

Comment: :-) i am such a fool. it is frozen now!

Comment: I appreciate the effort but what I want to achieve is to extend the kendo-grid without having to change anything in the controller. If I use a kendo-grid directly into the controller I don't have to do anything for the "mainGrid" to be recognized - it is generated with this line: **kendo-grid="mainGrid"**.

Comment: I want to add an extra layer (to encapsulate the kendo-grid into a directive so I can extend it). So I need to be able to use the directive *as if it were the kendo-grid itself*, meaning obtaining the **mainGrid** creation (to be used in the controller) by simply saying **my-grid-id="mainGrid"** (and the directive to further instatiate the kendo-grid and perform the proper binding between it and the controller)

Comment: yeeey: I managed to do it: http://plnkr.co/edit/SrMksOM8ZWcEiOKRAxi0?p=preview
I made my directive to be of Attribute type and placed it on the kendo-grid definition: `<div kendo-grid="mainGrid" k-options="mainGridOptions" id="mainGrid" my-grid >` so that both the controller and the directive can have access to the same instance of kendo-grid

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ocket-san for taking the time to look at this.

Eventually I got what I wanted: to extend the kendo-grid inside a directive without affecting any controller implementations which use the kendo-grid.

I managed to do this by creatting a directive of **Attribute** type which extends the current definition (usage) of the kendo-grid, so wherever I wish to add my extensions I can simply add my directive as an attribute:

```
<div kendo-grid="mainGrid" k-options="mainGridOptions" id="mainGrid" my-grid >
```

Instead of:

```
<div kendo-grid="mainGrid" k-options="mainGridOptions" id="mainGrid">
```

(**fyi**: I wanted to set **pagination** buttons to both **top** and **bottom** for all the kendo-grids in my application, without having to duplicate the extension all over the place)

See plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SrMksOM8ZWcEiOKRAxi0?p=preview).